# Parse Facebook, retrieving names separately

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, parse-platform

I'm looking to try to retrieve the user's facebook first name and last name separately in order to set them to my database. I have two columns, on for the `firstName` and one for the `lastName`

So far I have the following code that correctly outputs both the first and last name as a single string:

```
FB.api('/me', function(response) {
 console.log('Your name is ' + response);
});
```

I've also tried this example from the [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/reference/FB.api):

```
FB.api('/me', {fields: 'last_name'}, function(response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

but this returns an object along with the user's id.

How could I retrieve both the user's first name as last name and set them as two separate variables in my database, something like so:

```
currentUser.set("firstName",fbFirstName);
currentUser.set("lastName",fbLastName);
currentUser.save();
```

Thanks!

Comment: Which Parse SDK are you using?

Comment: The JavaScript SDK v.1.3.4